# WooCommerce Change Total Price on Checkout by custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I'm struggling finding a solution to this problem:

I need to create a custom number field on checkout page and change total price according to this field. 
The user can put a number starting from 4 to maximum the total Cart quantity and gets a discount based on this number.

How can I update total price after user set number field?

Below there is my code to add a custom field to checkout page

```
/**

* Add custom field to the checkout page

*/

add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'custom_number_field');

function custom_number_field($checkout)

{

echo '<div id="custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('Vuoto a rendere') . '</h2>';

woocommerce_form_field('custom_field_name', array(

'type' => 'number',

'class' => array(

'my-field-class form-row-wide'

) ,

'label' => __('Quanto vuoi rendere?') ,

'placeholder' => __('New Custom Field') ,

) ,

$checkout->get_value('custom_field_name'));

echo '</div>';

}
```

Then I read that it's not possible updating total price directly into checkout page and I need to refresh page using a button and passing to the new page the value of my custom field.

So I need to use this WooCommerce field:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'change_calculated_total', 10, 2 );
function change_calculated_total( $total, $cart ) {
    return $total - "value of my custom field";
}
```

How can I create a button link with the value of my custom field and pass it to the WooCommerce function to update cart?
I was thinking to use php GET and putting the value of custom field inside the link button and then retrieve the value from the link inside the cart function.

Some help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you got the solution ?